# Expression "My Scrotum"

Tags: phrases, slang

You know, for example, when you upload at a site a music you think good(**not for the purpose of learning English but just for its own fun sake there is no such site at SE unfortunately, PLEASE UNDERSTAND**), when there is a reply saying,

> ♪My scrotum♪

What would he mean? When I googled by "scrotum", that part of male's reproductive organ appeared, but I have no idea what he would try to mean. Can I take it literally? You SE people might think that I should ask at the ESL site of the site this question, but I look stupid.(Since people at the site always check what I am doing at the background.) So I am waiting for kind people's help.

If **some (limited) kind people who can save me really** need what kind of situation it really is, please check [**at this site.**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/lje3kx/the_knack_my_sharonaearly_rock/) user(the op) u/universexf6 is me.

Comment: [When you upload a song to  site/when you download a song from a site]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. But I would like to refrain from doing so because some people really hate Reddit so that I will not ask Reddit related questions anymore. See, Michael Harvery says it is even "deplorable". Thank you^^.

Comment: The issue is not about Reddit. It's about the usage here of the word. Personally, I think the question is useful as it deals with tropes re music and/or online culture and language. In English, somebody makes a comment and another can answer "My ass". Therefore, for me, this is a take off on that. [a take off is an satirical interpretation of something.]

Comment: Since answering, I've asked the originator of the phrase to comment! https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/comments/lje3kx/the_knack_my_sharonaearly_rock/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an idiom

The OP links to a reddit forum with a posting of "My Sharona" a new wave song by The Knack.

The music signs suggest it is to be read as "singing"

So I suppose the poster is just saying that it sounds as if the singer is singing "my scrotum" (as my skuh-roh-tum) instead of "my Sharona". And on this [list of 'misheard lyrics'](http://www.amiright.com/misheard/song/mysharona.shtml), there is a posting for "My scrotum" as a mishearing of "my Sharona"

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

**Since answering, I have asked the originator to comment!**

> 10 hours ago ”My scrotum.”
>
> Hi, can you settle an argument on a language forum? Some say that
> this is a comment on the quality of the song. I and some others say it
> is a 'misheard' lyric. Can you enlighten us as to its origin? Thanks.
> Hi, can you settle an argument on a language forum for us please? Some say that this is a comment on the quality of the song. I and some others say it is a 'misheard' lyric ("My sca-rotum"). Can you enlighten us as to its origin? Thanks.

---

It is very common for people to mis-hear lyrics of songs when the singer does not pronounce them clearly. In fact there are websites dedicated to this phenomenon.

I recommend searching online for ***misheard lyrics***  You will find hundreds of examples.

**Adele - Chasing Pavements**

[image]

---

Sometimes people deliberately pretend to mis-hear for comedic effect.

**Annie Lennox - Sweet Dreams are Made of This**

[image]

---

**Answer**

In this particular case it is possible to hear **My Sharona** as **My sca-rotum.**

Comment: "Scrotum" is not a malapropism. Never was, never will be.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - You probably don't have much experience with the humour of young teenage boys. Look at some of the unlikely "mistakes" on this website. http://www.amiright.com/misheard/   Quite a few of them are anatomical in nature.

Comment: A malaproprisms are a matter for the listener and can be heard from anything. They are not set a priori. This explanation seem rather likely.

Comment: Correction: A malaproprism is etc. And  I think that these questions can serve a purpose given how confusing the online realities are today....

Comment: @ Mari-Lou  - I've asked the originator - If they answer, let's see what the truth is!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Ahm....thank you for your kindness, but personally I would like to stop around here...

Comment: I've started so I'll finish.  I'm curious as to the answer.